# Why does element.style.display is blank if display declared on CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Why does this JS return blank if the style is declared in CSS, and works good when declared inline?

```
//html
<img id="myImg" src="http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png" />
<img id="myImg2" src="http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png" style="display:none;" />

/css
#myImg {
    display:none;
}

//vanilla JS
var el = document.getElementById('myImg');
var el2 = document.getElementById('myImg2');
console.log(el.style.display); // blank
console.log(el2.style.display); // 'none' - as expected
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3eyAF/)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `style` property maps onto the HTML `style` **attribute**, not the cascaded or computed style.

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) if you want to get that.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign properties in the manner above you are essentially just modifying the `style` attribute of that element.